# Clean way to include HTML in Script# projects

Tags: script#

Is there a way of embedding a html file in a script# project so that it can be included in controls rather than having to put it in a class property/field?

When I say html file, I'm refering to small snippets of html that I want to use in controls, not full size html documents that are better placed in the actual web project.

I have a hacky way of doing this by creating a .html file which is really a cs file that's set to compile and has the necessary namespace/class declarations in it, with a property called template that then has the html in it. Visual Studio kinda puts up with it, but it's clunky, for example, it means that you have to use single quotes instead of double quotes on attributes, etc.

Some other things I've looked at but don't quite fit what I'm after:

- jquery templating.
- including the file in my web project and loading it via ajax when needed.

It would be great if you could embed a html file in the project as a resource and have the script# compiler provide it via a ResourceManager.GetString() or similiar.

Any suggestions on alternative ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I've been doing the same thing. Even posted source code, as I've gotten sophisticated about how I encapsulate html fragments. I still ultimately rely on a .html as C# trick, but I have developed some other code you may find useful. https://github.com/duckmaestro/Sharp-UI

Comment: I've posted a feature request: https://github.com/NikhilK/scriptsharp/issues/30.

Comment: My method came directly from seeing your sample code (which is a great idea btw), I had just forgotten where I had seen it. I will take a look at the github feature request discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good discusssion going on over in the Script# issues list here:

https://github.com/NikhilK/scriptsharp/issues/30

For now I've settled on a T4 template which generates my code for me:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>

<#
 var namespaceName = System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalGetData("NamespaceHint");
 var baseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
#>

namespace <#= namespaceName #> {
<#= Run(baseDir) #>
}

<#+ 

    private string Run(string baseDir) {
      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      ProcessDirectory(baseDir, output);
      return output.ToString();
    }

    private void ProcessDirectory(string directoryPath, StringBuilder sb) {

      string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.htm");

      string template = @"
  public partial class {1} {{
    public string Template = @""{2}"";
  }}
";

      foreach (var file in files) {

        string theNameSpace = "TheNamespace";
        string className = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

        var text = File.ReadAllText(file).Replace("\"", "\"\"");
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format(template, theNameSpace, className, text));

      }

      var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);

      foreach (var directory in directories) {
        ProcessDirectory(directory, sb);
      }

    }

#>
```

Comment: How do you use this in the context of a script sharp and a asp.net mvc project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to hear why templates don't work ... the nice thing about the template approach is keeps the separation between code/logic and ui.

That said, you could try to create a resx with a string containing your HTML, and change the generator/custom tool associated with the resx to ResXInternalScriptGenerator - this will generate a resources class you can use within the script# project. I personally don't think the resx approach is that friendly to authoring chunks of HTML. If I had to embed in code rather than use templates, I'd just do it in c# ... unless there was also a localization element to the HTML.

Hope that helps.

Comment: re the templates. It's nice to be able to new up a js object which represents a widget, and the constructor be able to create an instance of itself, including it's html, all from within the library. It's working nicely now by having the widget's html in a cs file with the extension set to .html so that vs color codes it, but it would be great if it could just be a regular html file. I haven't gotton as far as to make this library available to other projects yet, but that could be another reason to include the html in the script library rather than in the web project.

Comment: You lost me on the ResXInternalScriptGenerator. I tried what you described, but I get the following error: "Cannot find custom tool 'ResXInternalScriptGenerator' on this system"

Comment: Oops - it should have been: ScriptSharp.ResourceModel.ResXInternalScriptGenerator

Comment: So close. I dragged my html file into the 'Files' section of the resource file, and could then access the generated field on the resource.cs, but it doesn't give me back the html from the file, just the file name and assembly version. Almost!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting putting the html file in the files section of a resx. I was implying creating a string name/value pair containing the identifier/markup within the resx. Alternatively there is the discussion of creating a custom tool aka VS SingleFileGenerator/T4 template to convert an html file into a bit of code.